Bluetooth not working on kernel 6.9.0 rc6
I installed this new kernel on my ubuntu 24 because my speakers didnt work on 6.8. But now, speakers work and bluetooth doesnt. I have hp envy 15 laptop. Here is the output to systemctl status bluetooth:
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-05-05 18:24:05 CEST; 3min 20s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 978 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18261)
     Memory: 2.8M (peak: 3.3M)
        CPU: 55ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─978 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 05 18:24:05 ig0r-hp-envy-x360-15 bluetoothd[978]: Starting SDP server
May 05 18:24:05 ig0r-hp-envy-x360-15 bluetoothd[978]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support csip plugin
May 05 18:24:05 ig0r-hp-envy-x360-15 bluetoothd[978]: profiles/audio/micp.c:micp_init() D-Bus experimental not enabled
May 05 18:24:05 ig0r-hp-envy-x360-15 bluetoothd[978]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support micp plugin
May 05 18:24:05 ig0r-hp-envy-x360-15 bluetoothd[978]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support vcp plugin
May 05 18:24:05 ig0r-hp-envy-x360-15 bluetoothd[978]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support mcp plugin
May 05 18:24:05 ig0r-hp-envy-x360-15 bluetoothd[978]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bass plugin
May 05 18:24:05 ig0r-hp-envy-x360-15 bluetoothd[978]: src/plugin.c:plugin_init() System does not support bap plugin
May 05 18:24:05 ig0r-hp-envy-x360-15 systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service.
May 05 18:24:05 ig0r-hp-envy-x360-15 bluetoothd[978]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
~

here is my output for sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth:
[    3.797133] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.797173] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.797175] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.797183] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.797187] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.797194] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.911248] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for mediatek/BT_RAM_CODE_MT7961_1a_2_hdr.bin failed with error -2
[    3.911256] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load firmware file (-2)
[    3.911259] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to set up firmware (-2)
[    3.911262] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[    6.008124] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.008130] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.008137] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

EDIT
I did download the necessary bin file, but still doesnt work. That error is gone though. Here is the new output for dmesg command:
[    3.073975] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.074004] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.074006] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.074013] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.074016] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.074022] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.124079] Bluetooth: hci0: HW/SW Version: 0x008a008a, Build Time: 20210821171156
[    5.027280] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.027286] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.027294] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.315588] Bluetooth: hci0: Mediatek coredump end
[   15.936643] Bluetooth: hci0: Execution of wmt command timed out
[   15.936662] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send wmt func ctrl (-110)
[   15.936671] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[   21.056670] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to write uhw reg(-110)
[   26.176961] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read uhw reg(-110)
[   31.297078] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to write uhw reg(-110)
[   36.443546] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to write uhw reg(-110)
[   41.718270] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read uhw reg(-110)

What should I do?

read and follow this thread. For a workaround, you can get the file from the bug report here. I am not sure of the status of any fix, but try -rc7 when it comes out shortly. Note that the mainline kernels are experimental and not really supported here.

You can get the file from https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=306191 extract the file and copy it to /lib/firmware/mediatek,  then reboot

@DougSmythies  I did like you said. Still doesn't work. Here is the new output for dmesg command

@Jeremy31 I did that. Here is the new output for dmesg

Looks like it needs more kernel support, have to wait I guess
